# Function with Return

Tags: function-construction

A simple function that adds 3 to all input and return a list containing the input and the output:

```
test[h_] := {
   g = h + 3;
   Return[{h,g}];
   };
```

When I evaluate it with `test[5]`, I get:

> {Return[{5, 8}]}

but I would like to get: `{5, 8}`

Comment: Just write `test[h_] := {h, h + 3}` `Return` is only needed for special purposes in Mathematica.

Answer (score 9):

You have the wrong type of brackets.  Your version is returning a `List` (which retains the `Return` object).

Also, `Return` is used to break out of control structures.  Basic return of variables is automatic; you don't need to use `Return` in your example.

Here the bracket are corrected.

```
test[h_] := (
  g = h + 3;
  Return[{h, g}];)

test[5]
```

> {5, 8}

The above is actually returning from the expression group *before* it hits the suppressing semi-colon.

Without `Return` the semi-colon suppresses output.

```
test[h_] := (
  g = h + 3;
  {h, g};)

test[5]
```

> *null*

To fix this you can just omit the final semi-colon.

```
test[h_] := (
  g = h + 3;
  {h, g})

test[5]
```

> {5, 8}

**Why did Return appear?**

Comparing two simple cases

```
test[h_] := Return[{h, h + 3}]

test[5]
```

> {5, 8}

```
test[h_] := {Return[{h, h + 3}]}

test[5]
```

> {Return[{5, 8}]}

The reason is mentioned [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Dec/msg00329.html)

> The very last step of the evaluation loop is ...
>
> "Discard the head Return, if present, for expressions generated
>   through application of user-defined rules."

In the second case the head is `List` so the `Return` is not discarded.

Comment: Nice ! when do I have to use module then, as suggested by @henry ?

Comment: `Module` is mainly used for localizing variables.  In henry's example `g` is localized and will not affect another `g` outside the module.

Comment: How do you index the returned list later? whenever I try running `test[5][[0]]` I get `List` as output...

Comment: @gen In Mathematica lists are one-indexed, so they begin at 1.  So you can use `test[5][[1]]` to obtain 5.  The zeroth item is the Head : see the [Head](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) - Properties & Relations section : "The head is the part with index 0".

Answer (score 4):

You can use modules:

```
test[h_] := Module[{g},
   g = h + 3;
   Return[{h, g}]];
```

As suggested by @m_goldberg  the function can be simplified:

```
test[h_] := Module[{g},
   g = h + 3;
   {h, g}];
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you removed `Return` and made the last line in the module just `{h, g}`

Comment: @m_goldberg added it. Thanks for the input.